# Flutter: Can we make a game online and integrate it to our flutter app?

Tags: flutter, 2d-games

I am trying to have a games section on the app that I am making for kids. Is there a way that I can use a 3rd party game maker (preferably online) and integrate it to my flutter app ? I don't want to use flutter's flame engine.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Unity package for flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget) if not flame.